# Object members not receiving values in C++

Tags: c++, member

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class stats
{
    int arr_size, median1, median2, occurrences;
    string data;
    int* arr;

    void setValues()
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) { arr[i] = rand() % 99 + 1; }

        sortArray();
    }
    void sortArray()
    {
        int min_index;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr_size - 1; i++)
        {
            min_index = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr_size; j++) { if (arr[j] < arr[i]) { min_index = j; } }
            swap(this->arr[i], this->arr[min_index]);
        }
    }
    void swap(int& x, int& y)
    {
        int temp;
        temp = x;
        x = y;
        y = temp;
    }

    double getMean()
    {
        double total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) { total += arr[i]; }
        return total / arr_size;
    }
    int getMedian()
    {
        if (arr_size % 2 == 0) { median1 = arr[(arr_size / 2) - 1]; this->median2 = arr[arr_size / 2]; }
        else { median1 = arr[arr_size / 2]; }
        return median1;
    }
    int getMode()
    {
        int count = 1, max_count = 1, mode;
        mode = arr[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i - 1] == arr[i]) { count += 1; mode = arr[i]; }
            else if (arr[i - 1] != arr[i])
            {
                if (count > max_count) { max_count = count; mode = arr[i - 1]; }
                count = 1;
            }
        }
        this->occurrences = max_count;
        return mode;
    }
public:
    stats(string str = "", int size = 1) : data{ str }, arr_size{ size } { arr = new int[size]; setValues(); }
    ~stats() { delete arr; arr = nullptr; }

    void printValues()
    {
        cout << this->data << endl << endl;
        cout << "Mean: " << getMean() << endl;

        this->median1 = getMedian();
        if (arr_size % 2 == 0) { cout << "Median 1: " << this->median1 << endl << "Median 2: " << this->median2 << endl; }
        else { cout << "Median: " << this->median1 << endl; }

        int mode = getMode();
        cout << "Mode: " << mode << " with " << this->occurrences << " occurrences." << endl;

        // Testing purposes
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) { cout << "arr[" << i << "]: " << arr[i] << endl; }
    }
};
```

So this is my code, and basically all I have to do is get the mean, median(s), and mode, along with its occurrences. It wasn't hard to build at all, but if you run it, `median2` and`occurrneces` don't receive the values. Why is this?

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger yet?

Comment: Some people don't trust code which has `void main`.

Comment: `static_cast<double>(total / arr_size);` won't give you what you think it should.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: I only included the `main` function just to show that I was only calling the one `public` function.

Comment: Currently I use Visual Studio 2015 Community.
And also the debugger didn't give any warnings. It runs smoothly, expect for those two missing values.

Comment: Consider this: Does your `getMode` function assume that the array is sorted? And if so, *is* the array that it receives sorted?

Comment: @AndyG I forgot to sort it! Wow! Sorry about that! Fairly new to C++. Give me just a moment! :)

So I tried to sort it (all I did was put `sort(arr[0], arr[arr_size-1]);` in the `setValues()` function, and it produced 5 errors. :/
Should I try sorting a different way?

Comment: @Ghost_Programmer: You could look into `std::sort` in the `<algorithm>` library.

Answer (score 2):

`median2` only gets a value if the size of the array is even (re-layed out for clarity):

```
if (arr_size % 2 == 0) {
    median1 = arr[(arr_size / 2) - 1];
    this->median2 = arr[arr_size / 2];
}
else { 
    median1 = arr[arr_size / 2];
}
return median1;
```

Also you should read up on statistics; in order to get any median of a distribution the samples need to be *sorted*, which you don't seem to do.

And this is also the reason why `occurrences` doesn't get the **right** value (it does get a value, only not the one you expect).

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the order of evaluation of parameters is unspecified, but your code is relying on them to be evaluated left-to-right.

```
// getMode() and this->occurrences may be evaluated in any order...
cout << "Mode: " << getMode() << " with " << this->occurrences << " occurrences." << endl;
```

You could store the results of your functions in variables:

```
int median1 = getMedian();
if (arr_size % 2 == 0) { cout << "Median 1: " << median1 << endl << "Median 2: " << this->median2 << endl; }
else { cout << "Median: " << median1 << endl; }

int mode = getMode();
cout << "Mode: " << mode << " with " << this->occurrences << " occurrences." << endl;
```

but the better solution is to restructure your code so it doesn't rely on the ordering of side effects.